# grunt-ng-annotate all angularjs files

Tags: angularjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, ng-annotate

I want to run ng-annotate via grunt on all my project's angular files.
Could not find this option.

I only have the option annotate by specify file name.

```
ngAnnotate: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'output_file_name.js': ['input_file_name'],
            },
        }
    }
```

I need something more generic that would run recursively on a specific directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the other configuration to go through folders and annotate each file which will be outputted in a `*.annotated.js` file.

```
ngAnnotate: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['**/*.js', '!**/*.annotated.js'],
                ext: '.annotated.js',
                extDot: 'last'
            }],
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike, But Isn't it will concat all *.js files into output_file_name.js?

Comment: Indeed, I've updated my answer which will annotate each file separately and write an `.annotated.js` version of it

Comment: Thanks @Mike, just want to emphasis that there are 2 things important to notice: 1. the array form of "files", 2. the src: ['**/*.js'] form for multiple files